# Can i raise the drain entrance with a 90 degree bend inside the wall?

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink, vanity

I want to raise the entrance into the wall for this vanity drain. I would put a 90 degree bend in the wall exactly where you see the existing pipe and run about 10" vertical and come out up there to accommodate a vessel sink. [image] Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you get us a wider view, too? It appears that the wall is drywall (frayed edges around the hole), but what's with the horizontal lines? Is there some sort of ledge or v-groove detail in the wall? What's with the slatted wooden thing in the foreground? Odds are good that there's already a 90° elbow changing from a vertical pipe to this horizontal stub - you'd want to make a straight joint there and have the single 90° come out higher. Can it be done? Sure. Can you? We don't know your skills. Could you learn it? Most likely.

Comment: It's hard to tell, but it looks like you want to shorten the drainpipe not make it 10" higher... I'd imagine that you'd want the pipe to come up through the countertop (is that the wood planks in the foreground?) not over the top. Also, in either case you'd probably not want to add another 90-degree bend but rather add (or subtract) straight pipe.

Comment: The drain runs horizontally to the left in the wall. The lines are shadows. The wood planks is a vanity. I just want to move it up the wall about 8 inches. This would involve replacing the drywall.

Comment: @DougieFresh the lines pointed to by [these arrows](https://i.imgur.com/Z8Fv3ME.jpg) are shadows? You've got some _interesting_ lighting going on in your bathroom.

Comment: The top of the vanity is not installed yet. The "mysterious shadows" is the top rail of the vanity casting a shadow against the wall. Hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a vertical 90 within the wall as that would result in the grade on the trap arm (the pipe from the vent connection to the p-trap) exceeding the allowable fall (the diameter of the trap arm pipe).

You could open the wall and raise the sanitary tee to the desired height or install the p-trap directly to the pipe as it exists the wall and turn the trap 90 degrees (parallel with the wall). Then you can go vertical off the p-trap to the sink. This is called an offset p-trap.

[image]

The first two sketches illustrate typical pipe configuration for a sink. The green indicates the trap arm which cannot grade more than the diameter of the pipe. You could open the wall and move this tee up further.

The third sketch illustrates my interpretation of what you want to do. You can see that the fall on the trap arm would exceed the pipe diameter.

The forth and fifth sketches illustrate an offset p-trap arraignment that would not require opening the wall.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Raising the inlet without also raising the vent connection results in what's known as an S-trap arrangement. That's typically not allowed by code since it can result in siphoning of the trap, leaving it dry (or at least leaking gas).

[image]

<sub>[Image source](https://homeandgardenmakeover.com/s-trap-vs-p-trap-whats-the-difference/)</sub>

The best solution would be to open the wall, cut out the sanitary tee, and raise it as an assembly.